# IOB format as output of parser

Tags: nlp

Is there any function in Standford NLP and OpenNLP to get output of parsing in IOB format? I need to use parser for NP chunking of sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need NP chunks, use the OpenNLP chunker instead of a parser.

It sounds like it might help you to read more about the differences between chunking and parsing, for example in the [NLTK docs on partial parsing](http://nltk.sourceforge.net/doc/en/ch06.html).  Although you could extract NPs from the output of a parser if you wanted, a normal parse couldn't be represented in IOB format or converted to IOB format.